# Problem with 2D vector in c++ when printing

Tags: c++, vector

```cpp
class Vertex {
    public:
    int dist, num;
    vector<Vertex*> edges;
    Vertex() {}
    Vertex(int num) : num(num) {}
};
class K {
public:
    void updateMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        vector<vector<Vertex>> vec;
        for (vector<int> in : matrix) { 
            vector<Vertex> neu;
            vec.push_back(neu);
            for (int i : in) {
                Vertex k(i);
                cout << k.num;
                neu.push_back(k);
            }
        }
        for (vector<Vertex> in : vec) {
            for (Vertex i : in) cout << i.num << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

When I call the function with a valid 2D vector, when I try to print `vec` the output is just 3 blank lines. How can I fix this?

Comment: You place a copy of the empty `neu` into `vec`, then you put elements in `neu` afterwards. Move the `vec.push_back(neu);` line to after you've put elements in `neu`

Comment: @TedLyngmo so when dealing with objects of the stack, vector<Object on stack> always copies the hole object?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the objects are on the stack or the heap. If you `push_back` into a `vector` a copy of what you `push_back` is put into the `vector`.

Comment: @Jacob By the way, you're making unnecessary copies in your for loops by doing `for(T in: vec)` instead of `for(const T& in: vec)`. If it's recent, I bet your compiler is giving you warnings about that.

Comment: By the way, you can save yourself a great deal of trouble by importing a matrix library (e.g. Eigen: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vec.push_back(neu);` puts a *copy* of the (empty) variable `neu` into `vec`. Changes to `neu` after this don't affect the copy.

You should move that to after the inner loop.