# Vector of pointer objects, problem while printing/iterating

Tags: c++

```cpp
class Vertex {
    public:
    int dist;
    int num;
    vector<Vertex*> edges;
    Vertex() {}
    Vertex(int num) : num(num) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    void updateMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        vector<vector<Vertex*>> bunker;
        for (const vector<int>& in : matrix) { 
            vector<Vertex*> neu;
            for (int i : in) {
                Vertex k(i);
                Vertex* v = &k;
                neu.push_back(v);
            }
            bunker.push_back(neu);
        }
        for (const vector<Vertex*>& b : bunker) for (Vertex* k : b) cout << k->num << endl;
    }
};
```

When inputting the matrix {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} the function only prints 9's. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you please share how you "intpu" that matrix?

Comment: This looks like leetcode problem. Please provide link to problem description so we could know what is expected result.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. You push in `neu` a pointer to an object that'll be destroyed right after... So next, you try to access destroyed object.

Comment: OP asked essentially the same question 1 hour ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056483/problem-with-2d-vector-in-c-when-printing The issue is in the same code. I would rather not see a new question at every stage of problem-solving.

Answer (score 3):

```
            Vertex k(i);
```

This declares a local variable in this loop, called `k`.

Like all other variables declares in automatic scope, this object will get automatically destroyed at the end of its scope.

```
            Vertex* v = &k;
            neu.push_back(v);
```

Immediately afterwards, a pointer to this object is added to a vector. And immediately after that, the object gets destroyed, leaving a pointer to a dangling reference behind to a destroyed

The rest of the code, that attempts to use these pointers to destroyed objects, is undefined behavior and you cannot expect any meaningful results, any more.

Answer (score 0):

> What did I do wrong?

You pushed pointers to objects that were about to cease to exist to your vector. By the time you try to use them they are long gone. Your program has undefined behaviour.

Rather than use pointers, just use `Vertex` directly.